# Excel, searching patterns from a set of data

Tags: excel

I am so new to excel, I don't know much about Excel, but I'm trying to do the following:

if a I had a set of data from column A to column E:

ABCDE

1   2   3   4   5

1   2   3   4   5

1   1   2   2   4

1   1   2   2   4

1   1   2   2   4

0   2   3   6   9

0   2   3   6   9

0   2   3   6   9

0   2   3   6   9

Let's say I have hundreds of rows of data, what I need to do is show what combinations and the number of times each occurs. At least 3 digits.

Combination    times

0-1-2                   0 times

1-2-3                   5 times (2+3) because 1-1-2-2-4 match in 3 digits, appears 3 times

2-3-4                   9 times (2+3+4)because 1-1-2-2-4 match in 3 digits, appears 3 times

```
                    and 0-2-3-6-9 match in 3 digits, appears 4 times
```

.

.

.

7-8-9                   0 times

0-1-3                   0 times

0-1-4                   3 times because 1-1-2-2-4 match in 3 digits
.

.

.

Any idea how I could do this? Sorry for poor English.

Comment: This seems fairly complex - please add a [small example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the input you expect and output you want for say 5 lines. Comma-separated lists are probably ideal for display. You can put four spaces in front of a line to mark it as a code block, which may aid readability too.

Comment: please wait a sec, i will upload a picture soon

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved? If so, please post your answer.

Answer (score -1):

1. Assume that you have Column titles in the first row, followed by the digits in columns A to E
2. Paste the following formula in column F (cell F2 downwards)
   =A2&B2&C2
   (Assuming that you need to consider only first 3 digits
3. Now Select column F and using the ADVANCED option in the SORT&FILTER ribbon, copy all the unique rows in column F to Column H. (Remember to use the "Unique Records Only" option in the "advanced filter" dialog
4. Now paste the following formula in Column I (Cell I2 downwards)
   =COUNTIF(F$2:F$100,"=" & H2)

Comment: i preferred not only the first 3 digits, is match 3 numbers of total 5 in a row